# Why after collection.replaceOne my res.statusCode changed from 200 to 404?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

For some reason after calling

```
collection.replaceOne({_id: newObj._id}, newObj)
```

res.statusCode changed from 200 Ok to 404 Not Found. What can cause this problem? Here is my code:

```
const updatePost = (req, res, next) => {
  const { user } = req.session;
  const params = req.body;
  const collection = req.conn.db(db).collection('posts');
    try {
      const err = new Error();
      const [post] = await collection.find({ _id: new ObjectID(params._id) }).toArray();
      // some logic for checking params values
      await collection.replaceOne({ _id: new ObjectID(params.id) }, post);
      res.send({ error: false, message: 'Post updated.' });
      return next();
  } catch (err) {
    return next(err);
  }
};
```

It should replace doc in db, but for some reason it throws error with 404 response. Why it so?

Comment: in the replaceOne function you wrote `params.id` not `params._id` is it normal ?

Comment: Yes, it goes like this from frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Should the following code be inside the try block?

```
const collection = req.conn.db(db).collection('posts');
```

Comment: tried with collection initialization inside catch block, same result

Comment: Does your params.id exist in the database? Maybe it is missing.

Comment: yes, it takes the same stringified _id field from this doc. Before it I calling find by this id like this:
const [post] = await collection.find({ _id: new ObjectID(params._id) }).toArray();
I also tried to use just { _id: post._id} filter.